# Icon missing in panel shortcut

Tags: kde, plasma

I've been using OpenSuse (10+ years) and migrated to Ubuntu 16.04.

All my habits, all my needs for desktop are from the past, KDE3, KDE4.

I'm using kubuntu-desktop on ubuntu 16.04. Mostly all of my needs (except quanta plus - RIP) are satisfied.

My last problem is with app shortcuts in panel. I creat "link to app" on the desktop (standalone static version of app placed in my home) with custom icon (linked also from the app directory) all works ok, icon is presented. If I copy/move this link to app to the panel as seen in screenshot icon is missing. If I try to edit this shortcut there is empty dialog, only nonsense "keyboard sortcut" setting.

So how can I add proper icon for this icon shortcut?

[screenshot of desktop icon and icon in panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqRMH.png)

[dialog window for shortcut icon setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKf8T.png)

p.s. I have my reasons to use standalone version of firefox instead of repositories

Comment: Just right click on the K-Start button (the application launcher), and click 'Edit Applications'. You can change the path of an application there. More information is on the KDE webpage: https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kde-workspace/kmenuedit/quickstart.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just right click on the K-Start button (the application launcher), and click 'Edit Applications'.  This will bring up KDE Menu Editor and you can change the path of an application there.

[image: KDE Menu Editor]

Look at the picture in the link above to see how I modified Thunderbird.  I want to use a certain version of Thunderbird so I keep it in `/mnt/data/programs/thunderbird/thunderbird/` - the executable is `thunderbird`.  You can see that I added that to 'Command'.

Now when I save the menu item, I can drag it from the applications menu to the desktop or to my task bar and it will work as wanted.  Or, if I've already created the taskbar icon, the command will be updated there automatically.

Comment: Thx, worked. Dragging it from menu is ok, dragging it from desktop icons not. Strange behavior but solved. KDE is not so stable as was in 3,4 version :(